# TransitionGroup with react and redux: replace old element with animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reactcsstransitiongroup

Consider a use case: a block with a text inside (text is fetched from store). When text changes - block smoothly goes away and the other block appears.

Pseudo code for better illustration:

```
import TransitionGroup from 'react-addons-transition-group'

@connect((state) => ({text: state.text}))
class Container extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TransitionGroup>
          <Block key={this.props.text}/> // change block when text changes
        </TransitionGroup>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

@TransitionWrapper() // pass componentWillEnter through wrapper
@connect((state) => ({text: state.text}), null, null, {withRef: true})
class Block extends React.Component {
componentWillEnter(callback) {
    // fancy animations!!!
    const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this); 
    TweenMax.fromTo(el, 1, { 
      alpha: 0, 
    }, { 
      alpha: 1, 
      onComplete: callback 
    }); 
  }

  componentWillLeave (callback) { 
    const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this); 
    TweenMax.to(el, 1, { 
      alpha: 0, 
      onComplete: callback 
    }); 
  }

  render() {
     return (
       <div>{this.props.text}</div>
     )
   }
}
```

What happens when state.text changes?

1. New `Block` appears, because `key` is changed; `componentWillEnter` starts the animation for it. Great.
2. Old block gets *re-rendered* and `componentWillLeave` starts the animation for it.
3. When first animation finishes re-render happens again.

The issue is the step no 2: old element should disappear with the old data, but due to re-render it changes his content to a new one from `store`, so user see this:

1. `store.text = 'Foo'`. User see one Block with text 'Foo' on the screen.
2. `store.text = 'Bar'`. User see two Blocks, both with text 'Bar' on the screen. One block is disappearing.
3. Animation finishes, user see one Block with text `Foo` on screen.

I believe using transitions is pretty common nowadays and this should be a common issue, but I was surprised I couldn't find anything related.
Best idea I can think is to "freeze" props on the element when it's about to leave (or passing previous `store`, so it re-renders with previous data), but it feels hacky to me.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

We met the same problem with redux store, since when data got removed, the props contains nothing, thus, the UI will show no data when unmounting animation is happening.

I think it is hacky to use the old store or state (break the convention of React life Cycle), you can use `loading placeholder` if no data is available, like

```
if (!this.props.text){
   return <EmptyPlaceholder />
}
```

also the animation duration is small like `300` milliseconds, the user experience won't be bad.

**Alternatively**, you need to define a class instance variable like:

```
componentWillMount(){
       if(this.props.text){
         this.text = this.prop.text;  
       }
    }
```

Then render text like

```
<Block key={this.props.text || this.text}/>
```

Then the old text will always be there when unmounting animation happened. I tested on my project, it worked very well. Hopefully it will help u, if not please feel free to msg me.